# Remove url rewrites for registered taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, register-taxonomy

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856464/is-having-too-many-url-rewrites-in-my-htaccess-a-bad-thing) having many url rewrites doesn't slow down website. 
But neverthless is it possible to disable generating those rewrites when I register taxonomies? Becase only for this one CTP I have 60 unnecessary rewrites.

```
// Register CTP
$args = array(...)
register_post_type('my_ctp', $args);

// Register 12 months as taxonomy for CTP (each of them have a few custom terms inside)
foreach($this->months as $month => $month_var) {
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array('name' => $month),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'sort' => true,

    /*  'public' => false,
        'show_ui' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'query_var' => false*/
        );
    register_taxonomy($month_var, 'my_ctp', $args);     
}
```

This is example of a rewrite for one custom taxonomy
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the args try to add this :

```
"rewrite" => FALSE,
```

Comment: hm so simple, Ty how did I missed that... must be too late :)